# Linux, Lyx: "File undertilde.sty not found" error on previewing a file

Tags: lyx, linux

[image]

Linux Mint 18.3 KDE, Lyx 2.3.0.
No idea what this is all about. Tried googling but I can't find anything similar to my situation. Oddly enough I can still open older .lyx files normally without the error showing up, but I am trying to make a new file right now and I can't preview it. Neither .pdf nor html formats. Also, under Documents->Settings->Math Options the package "undertilde" is on always load.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `undertilde` package is not in TeX Live because it has no licensing information. Remove it from the settings.

Comment: Even when it's on "do not load" I still get the exact same window with the same error :/

Comment: Well, I'm not acquainted with LyX: I tried it and a few minutes later I removed it from my machine. Let's wait for somebody who uses it.

Comment: try uncommenting the package in your `.tex` and see if it works again.

Comment: @HarryK. Can you please post a minimal example file? Do you get the error when you start a new file and just put "hello" and select "do not load"? If so, can you please post that file, as described here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Alright so I solved this by opening the .Lyx file with a text editor and found any mentions of using the specific package and deleted them. It works fine now. Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.